# Windows XP Outlook 2003/2007 do not support Google image chart

Tags: php, google-visualization, outlook-2007, outlook-2003, windows-xp-sp2

I have image in mail which have `src` as `//chart.googleapis.com/chart` which is not displayed in outlook 2007/2003.

I have tried this setting

Click on Tools/File->Options>>Trust center>>Automatic Download>>
Unchecked Don't download pictures automatically in HTML email messages or RS S items >>OK

but it only displays normal images but not Google image chart.

I have also tried this `setup.exe` file for Google Map API link

http://cmapsys.com/P/MFO/Download.html

Please give me solution for this. It will be great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Outlook. When you don't specify the protocol in your URL, Outlook tries to use `file://` as the protocol and searches for the image on your local computer. You need to use a full `http://` or `https://` at the beginning of your image src URL.

Protocol relative URLs are great for the browser, but avoid them in HTML emails.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and let you know and its working on g-mail or yahoo.. etc but not on outlook.

Comment: @user2841211 That's because Gmail and Yahoo are browser based, where protocol-relative URLs work great!